# TROPOMI NO2 and tropospheric NO2 fields bugs

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I downloaded the monthly NO2 data for the city of Bogotá using the GEE platform. I am analyzing the monthly average for April 2020 of both total NO2 and tropospheric NO2.
A large amount of missing data is observed in the tropospheric NO2 field, while the total NO2 field is complete.

Is that due to an error in the calculation of tropospheric NO2 that Copernicus makes, or is it an error of the GEE platform when transforming the data from L2 to L3?

This happens for many months

I used the python GEEMAP library to export the Google API data to TIFF images. https://geemap.org/notebooks/11_export_image/

My code:

```
collection=ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2').select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density').filterDate(date_i,date_f)     

collection_img_mean=collection.mean().setDefaultProjection(collection.first().projection())     

geemap.ee_export_image_to_drive(collection_img_mean, description='Bogota+_' + date_i, region=AOI, scale=1113.2)
```

[image: tropospheric NO2, APRIL 2020, Bogotá][image: total NO2, APRIL 2020, Bogotá]

Comment: Which was used code?

Comment: I used GEEMAP https://geemap.org/notebooks/11_export_image/

Comment: OK, thanks. I voted for reopening.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this same problem, so it appears that GEE hasn't fixed it yet.

However, a rough solution is to **take the total column density and subtract the stratospheric column density from it to get the tropospheric density**. The TROPOMI instrument first calculates the slant column density and separates it into tropospheric and stratospheric components. Then, using the air mass factor, it finds respective tropospheric and stratospheric column densities. Total column density is never directly calculated in TROPOMI's pipeline.

Therefore, I am assuming that GEE simply summed the tropospheric and stratospheric column densities to get the total density. Furthermore, some testing has verified that the total density is the sum of the stratospheric and tropospheric densities for the tropospheric band values that do exist.

If the tropospheric density is urgently needed, then this solution works. But overall, this is definitely a problem that still needs fixing.

Edit: Turns out Earth Engine has modified the tropospheric NO2 layer to remove pixels with quality values less than 75%. If data isn't available, it is likely because it is too low quality. Regardless, the method above works if you'd like to have the data regardless.